# how to get object with retrofit library?

Tags: android, json, serialization, retrofit

i am first time trying to use retrofit library, and i got a problem.

here is my JSON:

```
{  
   "id":"15",
   "email":"example@gmail.com",
   "phone":null,
   "password":"",
   "login":"",
   "userProfile":{ 
      "lan_status":"",
      "name":"example",
      "sex":"0",
      "second_name":"",
      "date_of_birth":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   }
}
```

here is my retrofit code:

```
String url = "https://example.com";
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(url)
                .build();

        mServerApi = restAdapter.create(ServerApi.class);
mServerApi.getUserInformation( new Callback <GetUserProfileInfo> () {
            @Override
            public void success(GetUserProfileInfo getUserProfileInfo, Response response) {
                saveUserInfromationToDb(mActivity, getUserProfileInfo);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });

public class GetUserProfileInfo {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int mUserId;
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String mUserEmail;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    public String mUserPhone;
    @SerializedName("password")
    public String mUserPassword;
    @SerializedName("login")
    public String mUserLogin;
    @SerializedName("userProfile")
    public List<GetUserProfileInfo_2> userProfile;

}

public class GetUserProfileInfo_2 {
    @SerializedName("lanStatus")
    public int mLanStatus;
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    public String mFirstName;
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    public String mLastName;
    @SerializedName("sex")
    public int mSex;
}
```

but i got this problem:
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 533 path $.userProfile

will be glad any help!

Comment: Can you post your API URL?

Comment: userProfile is not a list/array

Comment: try  
@SerializedName("userProfile")
    public GetUserProfileInfo_2 userProfile;  
instead of 

 @SerializedName("userProfile")
    public List<GetUserProfileInfo_2> userProfile;

Comment: A good question that does not deserve 2 downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GetUserProfileInfo {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int mUserId;
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String mUserEmail;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    public String mUserPhone;
    @SerializedName("password")
    public String mUserPassword;
    @SerializedName("login")
    public String mUserLogin;
    @SerializedName("userProfile")
    public GetUserProfileInfo_2 userProfile;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON `userProfile` must be an object, not a list. Create another class with all those fields from `userProfile` and use this class instead of `List<GetUserProfileInfo_2>` for `userProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

you might benefit from having a look at an example app I made using the Stackoverflow REST API.  The object I get from the Retrofit call is a list of objects, so it seems quite fitting to your needs!

https://github.com/BrunoCa/stackrest
And that's the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bruno.stackrest

Enjoy